# go-iris Re-registering a service in an mvc application

Tags: go, go-iris

I am working on a heartbeat failure detector where on the front end I am using Iris and the front end is checking if the backend is alive.

The front end is an Iris mvc application done the following way:

```
app := iris.New()

app.StaticWeb("/", "./public")

// Configure the websocket server
ws := websocket.New(websocket.Config{})

jobAppsRouter := app.Party("/jobApplications")

jobAppsRouter.Any("/iris-ws.js", websocket.ClientHandler())

// Create the MVC object
jobApplicationsApp := mvc.New(jobAppsRouter)
```

Then I create my connection and I do the following

```
/ Create the service that interacts with the repo
jobAppService := services.NewJobApplicationService(conn)

// Dependencies
jobApplicationsApp.Register(
    jobAppService,
    ws.Upgrade,
)
// Controllers registration
jobApplicationsApp.Handle(new(controllers.JobAppController))
// Start the web server at http://localhost:8080
app.Run(iris.Addr(portStr))
```

This works and starts the app properly. The problem is that later on, I create a new connection to the same back end and I want to register a new service with it. Simply doing this again
    jobAppService := services.NewJobApplicationService(conn)

```
// Dependencies
jobApplicationsApp.Register(
    jobAppService,
    ws.Upgrade,
)
```

doesn't do what I need. What could I do?

Comment: You should ask the author of iris. (But best would be: Do not use iris.)

Comment: View [this post](http://www.florinpatan.ro/2016/10/why-you-should-not-use-iris-for-your-go.html) to assist in forming an opinion of iris.